# MSP430 Eclipse CDT (code composer v6): remove the echo statements "building", "invoking" "finished" from makefile

Tags: c, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, msp430, code-composer

I'm building a MSP430 project in code composer studio.  My CDT build reports `building file: [...]`, `invoking: [...]` then `finished building: [...]` for every file compiled.  This is a rather verbose output and unless I'm trying to fix/adjust something in the build process... just echoing thename of the file being build would be enough.

Digging into the makefile I didn't find the compile rule for c/cpp files (the default must be defined elsewhere?), but I did find for the link step and I assume the compile rule has similar verbosity.

```
@echo 'Building target: $@'
@echo 'Invoking: MSP430 Linker'
@"c:/ti/ccsv6/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-msp430_4.4.3/bin/cl430" ...
@echo 'Finished building target: $@'
@echo ' '
```

Note, I did manage to add the `@` to the compile statement to hide it's lengthy statement with all it's parameters.  See `Command` in:

```
Project -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> CCS Build
```

This didn't work for MinGW though (my test code)... `Program "@gcc" not found` <sigh...>.

Anyway, for the MSP430 build I still have the 4 remaining verbose echo statements for the MSP430 build.

Going further, I search the phrase `Building target:` in all sorts of files. no success.

Is there a way to remove/silence these extra echo statements??